# Import .ProvisionProfile when using Circle.CI and FastLane

Tags: continuous-integration, provisioning-profile, circleci, fastlane

For my personal project, I am using Circle.ci to test and deploy the OSX application (with upload hook to S3, to distribute it outside the AppStore - using the signed with Developer ID distribution method). I am using FastLane to build the app, which works flawlessly when building it from my local terminal, but I cannot get past code signing step when using the CI server.

The issue is very simple, the keychain does not import the provision profile, which I can tell from the pre-build step:

```
1 key imported.
No provisioning profiles found in repository. 
You must add a provisioning profile to your repository 
to enable CircleCI code-signing support.

Currently installed Code-Signing identities:

Policy: Code Signing
  Matching identities
     0 identities found

  Valid identities only
     0 valid identities found
```

I have my .p12 with private key and certificate uploaded to the repository, no issue there. I have also added the .provisionprofile to the repository (root, even different locations) but to no avail. The documentation states (https://circleci.com/docs/ios-code-signing/) that there is a need for .mobileprovision, but that only covers the iOS, not the OSX, while the system should be nearly identical so I assumed that would work as well.

So the TLDR question is: How do I import the provisioning profile of the OSX distribution on the Circle.CI, so the keychain accepts the entry? Or is there a way around it - like skipping the signing step (disabling it in XCode) and signing it by hand with some .sh?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my experience of deploying iOS app to Testflight using CircleCI. Maybe this helps.

1. Put the provision profile file in the root of your project directory. Make sure it is a normal "Distribution Profile" not a App Store submission profile.
2. Just add the .p12 key in the project settings of CircleCI. Remove all other certificates / .p12 file from the repository.
3. I tried using fastlane to build and distribute the build but it was failing in CircleCI. I had these three steps in my Fastfile beta environment.

`increment_build_number
gym(scheme: "myScheme”)
pilot`

I changed that to just
`increment_build_number`

4. My Circle CI file

   ```
   machine:

       environment:
           GYM_CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY: "iPhone Distribution: Company Name (XXXXXX)"

       xcode:
           version: "8.0"

   test:
       override:
         - set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace 'my.xcworkspace' -scheme 'myscheme' clean build test -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'id=AC291080-8EFE-4095-8C55-B1E952EFFC36' CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=  PROVISIONING_PROFILE=

   dependencies:
       pre:
         - gem update fastlane

   deployment:
       beta_distribution:
           branch: master
           commands:
              - fastlane beta      
              - gym --scheme "myscheme" --workspace "my.xcworkspace" --export_method app-store --use_legacy_build_api false     
              - pilot upload
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue, though, thank you for the configuration. I have many Circle.CI projects that are iOS-based and they work fine, no problem there. There is one difference with the OSX builds though - the Circle.CI does not find provisioning profile for the OSX (for iOS, you have .mobileprovision, while for OSX you have .provisionprofile).